# Using foreach and unset() to keep only a specific set of data in a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that contains category numbers collected from a database. The array is not static and could change in length and content.

Based on the result of an if/else statement I need to drop everything from the array apart from one specific category and it's subcategories.

I thought this was what I needed, but I don't get any content at all if I use this.

```
foreach($this->data[$parent_id] as $key => $value) {
if(!in_array($key, 131)) {
    unset($this->data[$parent_id][$key]);
}
}
```

What I thought i was doing was getting all the array data, and if the array key isn't 131, drop it.

Comment: shouldent you do this in your db query?

Comment: @rtfm The same db query is also passing data into a dropdown menu. Editing the query directly would restrict what's available to the dropdown. I would have thought it simpler to just modify the array data before passing it to the second function

Comment: @StevePrice, maybe you trying to achieve something different, but from your code, it seems that you do not need a loop. because array indexes are unique you can simply do the following: `$this->data[$parent_id] = [$this->data[$parent_id][131]];`.

Comment: @StevePrice while the answer I posted is functional, unless you have additional logic that would otherwise require a loop, you may want to consider sevavietl's suggestion. It would reach the same result in a one liner with better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, this is how your code reads:

```
/** For each, Array as $key => $value **/
foreach($this->data[$parent_id] as $key => $value) {
/** if needle $key is not found in Array 131, 
       which in this case is never **/
    if(!in_array($key, 131)) {
        /** destroy array[key], or in this case, all the elements**/
        unset($this->data[$parent_id][$key]);
    }
}
```

So the above should give you back an empty array. Refer to [php.net's in_array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to pass the appropriate parameters, in the appropriate order.

If all you are wanting to compare is the key of the current iteration of $this->data[$parent_id] with (e.g.) 131, then this is all you need:

```
/** For each, Array as $key => $value **/
foreach($this->data[$parent_id] as $key => $value) {
/** if the current $key of the array element is not equal to number 131 **/
    if($key != 131) {
        /** destroy the array element**/
        unset($this->data[$parent_id][$key]);
    }
}
```

**PS**: Updating my answer to reflect that, in this specific case, the loop logic above is equivalent to the following:

```
/** 
 * If key 131 exists in data[$parent_id]
 *   assign an array with only thisArray[131] as an element, 
 *   where thisArray is data[parent_id]
 **/
if(array_key_exists(131, $this->data[$parent_id]))
    $this->data[$parent_id] = [$this->data[$parent_id][131]];
```